# C# Shallow copy Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, shallow-copy

I need to shallow copy a dictionary in c#.

For instance:

```
Dictionary<int,int> flags = new Dictionary<int,int>();
flags[1] = 2;
flags[2] = 3;
flags[0] = 9001;
Dictionary<int,int> flagsn = flags.MemberwiseClone();
```

Unfortunately, that returns the error: "error CS1540: Cannot access protected member `object.MemberwiseClone()' via a qualifier of type`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'. The qualifier must be of type `PointFlagger' or derived from it"

Not entirely sure what this means... Is there another way to shallow copy a dictionary/fix my code above?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To get a shallow copy, just use the constructor of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` as it takes an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.  It will add this collection into the new instance.

```
Dictionary<int, int> flagsn = new Dictionary<int, int>(flags);
```

Comment: @Jared, Actually, it seems it doesn't accept an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>`, but a `IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary`

Answer (score 10):

This is a generic way I found where you don't have to explicitly write any type, which I prefer for maintainability reasons:

```
var ShallowCopy = OriginalDictionary.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: What is "kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value" in this context. How will i add key and value. It showing an error at my end

Comment: You need to add a using statement for `System.Linq` to access the ToDictionary() extension method.

Comment: I would strongly advise against doing this. The LINQ call is useful for deep copying, but has huge negative performance implications if all you want is a shallow copy.